# Mysql join distinct

Tags: mysql, join, relational-database

A query that returns all posts, along with how many times it was viewed, and how many likes the post have. problem is it return duplicates because of another join i have in query

```
        SELECT count(bv.postId) as views, SUM(if(vote=1, 1, 0)) as likes, SUM(if(vote=-1, 1, 0)) as meeh, GROUP_CONCAT(taxonomy_id) as target, GROUP_CONCAT(t.name) as tname, `t`.`type` as `ttype`, `users`.`fullname`, `users`.`picture`, `users`.`role`, `users`.`picture`, `blog`.* FROM `blog` 
INNER JOIN `blog_taxonomy` `bt` ON `bt`.`blog_id` = `blog`.`id` 
INNER JOIN `users` ON `users`.`id` = `blog`.`user_id` 
INNER JOIN `taxonomy` `t` ON `t`.`id` = bt.`taxonomy_id` 
LEFT JOIN `blog_views` `bv` ON `blog`.`id` = `bv`.`postId` 
WHERE MONTH(blog.time_posted) = 4 AND `blog`.`deleted` =0 GROUP BY `blog`.`id` ORDER BY `blog`.`id` DESC
```

blog_views table is a simple table i use to keep track of who saw what post, and if he like it or not

```
Table:blog_views 
postId  userId  vote[int values, 1 for like, -1 for dislike and 0 default]
```

problem is count of views always returns n*count of blog_taxonomy table! which i use to control tags on post.

```
Table blog_taxonomy:
taxonomy_id post_id
 1           1
 2           1
Table Taxonomy
 id  name
  1   art
  2   music
```

this is a many to many table used to link posts with tags. removing it from query solve the problem :( but i need it in there !

i tried adding bv.postId in the group by, but it seems to have no effect at all !

in normal, i can get views data i want for a post using

```
select count(bv.postId) as views, SUM(if(vote=1, 1, 0)) as likes, SUM(if(vote=-1, 1, 0)) as meet from blog_views where postId = ?{blog.id}
group by postId
```

what am i missing here ?

**edit**

using subquery fixed the problem. so why is subquery method bellow works and the join not working ?

```
SELECT bv.views, bv.likes, bv.meeh, GROUP_CONCAT(taxonomy_id) as target, GROUP_CONCAT(t.name) as tname, `t`.`type` as `ttype`, `users`.`fullname`, `users`.`picture`, `users`.`role`, `users`.`picture`, `blog`.* FROM `blog` 
INNER JOIN `blog_taxonomy` `bt` ON `bt`.`blog_id` = `blog`.`id` 
INNER JOIN `users` ON `users`.`id` = `blog`.`user_id` 
INNER JOIN `taxonomy` `t` ON `t`.`id` = bt.`taxonomy_id` 
LEFT JOIN (select count(*) as views,postId,SUM(if(vote=1, 1, 0)) as likes, SUM(if(vote=-1, 1, 0)) as meeh from `blog_views` group by postId) `bv` ON `bt`.`blog_id` = `bv`.`postId` 
WHERE MONTH(blog.time_posted) = 4 AND `blog`.`deleted` =0 GROUP BY `blog`.`id` ORDER BY `blog`.`id` DESC
```

Comment: from which table is `taxonomy_id` coming from?

Comment: @KP. blog_taxonomy

Comment: It seems to me you've answered your own question. If you're still confused, fire the same queries without the outer aggregate functions and group by clause.

Comment: @Strawberry english please :D ?

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand your JOIN condition on taxonomy table isn't right
`JOIN taxonomy t ON t.id = taxonomy_id`

1. add alias to `taxonomy_id` i.e. `bt.taxonomy_id`,  if this still doesn't work
2. make all the joins as INNER JOIN

Comment: just did that :(, still count return count of blog_taxonomy rows

Comment: can you post your table structures and sample data?

Comment: just did :). along with a fix i just found by trial and error !